# Javascript shift within a loop and the output arent functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

The function is run through a callback once the google map has loaded, however the title applied in the `draw()` function is only the value of the last entry in the array, this last date is then applied to all markers, not just the relevant ones.

The part that has me stumped that I applied the same idea to get markerCoords, yet that works perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Live Illness Mapper</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--  
 <button onclick="window.location.href = 'submit.html';"id="submBut" type="button">Report Illness</button> 
  -->
  <button class="btn" type="button" button onclick="$('#menu').toggle();">Toggle Buttons</button>
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="submit.html"><img class="navBtns" src="images/UI/AddIllness.png" alt="Add Illness"></a>
        <a href="illnessTable.php"><img class="navBtns" src="images/UI/RemoveIllness.png" alt="Remove Illness"></a>
        <a href="Form_for_occurrence.php"><img class="navBtns" src="images/UI/ReportAffliction.png" alt="Report Affliction"></a>
        <a href="Trends.html"><img class="navBtns" src="images/UI/Trends.png" alt="Trends"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDoKbEbUmn1CxDuS_1BfkKijGjkqa8kgq8&callback=showOccurrences">
    </script>
    <?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbusername = "--------------------";
    $dbpassword = "------------";
    $dbname = "-----------";
    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Postcode FROM Occurrence_Records");

    $a = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $a[] = $row['Postcode'];
    }

    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Date FROM Occurrence_Records");

    $b = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
        $b[] = $row['Date'];
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<script>
function showOccurrences(){
    var geocoder;
    var address;
    var markerCoords;
    var locations;
    var dates;
    var recorded;
    var a = <?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;
    var b = <?php echo json_encode($b); ?>;
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);

    var Worcester = {lat: 52.188, lng: -2.220};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 13,
      center: Worcester
    });

    while (a.length >0 && b.length >0){ //while the postcode array still has postcodes in it
        locations = a[0]; //value of the last postcode in the array
        dates = b[0];
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        address = locations;
        GeocodeMarker(a[0], b[0]);
        a.shift();
        b.shift();
        console.log(locations);
        console.log(dates);


        /* FIND SOMEWHERE TO LOOP PROPERLY DATE FOR MARKERS IN CONJUNCTION WITH POSTCODE - is currently only using last date ======================================

        */
    }

    function GeocodeMarker (address, dates){
       geocoder.geocode( { 
        'address': address}, 
        function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            markerCoords = results[0].geometry.location;
            createMarker(markerCoords, dates);
            //console.log(results[0].geometry.location
          } else {
          alert('Click ok to add illness markers');
          }
        });
    }


    function createMarker(){
        console.log(markerCoords, dates);
        var image = 'images/Logo/virus.png';
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          title: dates,
          position: markerCoords,
          map: map,

          icon: image

        });
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest passing the coordinates and the title (mouseover text) into the functions (rather than counting on global variables to work).

You would need two functions:

1. a `createMarker` function (replaces your `draw` function).
2. a `GeocodeMarker` function (replaces your `Geocoding` function).

```
function createMarker(markerCoords, date){
    var image = 'images/Logo/virus.png';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          title: date,
          position: markerCoords,
          map: map,
          icon: image
    });
}
function GeocodeMarker(address, date){
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        markerCoords =results[0].geometry.location;
        createMarker(markerCoords, date);
      } else {
        alert("Can't geocode: "+address+", status="+status);
      }
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6oerntyw/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
  showOccurrences();
}

function showOccurrences() {
  var geocoder;
  var address;
  var markerCoords;
  var locations;
  var dates;
  var recorded;
  var a = ["10007", "07102", "07649"]; // <?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;
  var b = ["1/1/2000", "2/2/2001", "3/3/2003"]; // <?php echo json_encode($b); ?>;
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);

  var Worcester = {
    lat: 52.188,
    lng: -2.220
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: Worcester
  });

  while (a.length > 0 && b.length > 0) { //while the postcode array still has postcodes in it
    locations = a[0]; //value of the last postcode in the array
    dates = b[0];
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    address = locations;
    GeocodeMarker(a[0], b[0]);
    a.shift();
    b.shift();
    console.log(locations);
    console.log(dates);
  }
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  function GeocodeMarker(address, date) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        markerCoords = results[0].geometry.location;
        createMarker(markerCoords, date);
      } else {
        alert("Can't geocode: "+address+", status="+status);
      }
    });
  }


  function createMarker(markerCoords, date) {
    console.log(markerCoords, date);
    var image = 'images/Logo/virus.png';
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      title: date,
      position: markerCoords,
      map: map,
    });
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```